# SPARQL to get all properties not working in local wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

The following SPARQL is from SQID python script to generate a properties.json. The following SPARQL would work in [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0A%09SELECT%20%3Fid%20%3FidLabel%20%3Ftype%0A%09WHERE%20%7B%0A%09%09%3Fid%20%3Fb%20wikibase%3AProperty%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fid%20wikibase%3ApropertyType%20%3Ftype%0A%09%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%09%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D)

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
    SELECT ?id ?idLabel
    WHERE {
        ?id ?b wikibase:Property .
        SERVICE wikibase:label {
            bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
        }
    }
```

Which resulted in `?id` being a list of properties (wd:P6 ,for example)
But in my blazegraph, it would return only

`<https://hostname/entity/statement/Q2344-EF3616F6-48B5-47A6-AA6B-372703F251C5>`

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: That the schema data isn't in your local Blazegraph of course

Comment: Sorry, i am quite new to this. Can you guide me to some resources to read about this schema?

Comment: All I'm saying is that the data isn't in your triple store, otherwise it would have been returned. And nobody here knows which dataset exactly you loaded. You can also check from commandline if such a triple is contained in the file you loaded to Blazegraph.

Comment: I found out the problem. the wikibase I use still pointing to othology-beta and in 2018, wiki team change it to othology.

Comment: it's called "ontology" not "othology"